# What is the fastest way to import to Neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a list of JSON documents, in the format:

```
[{a:1, b:[2,5,6]}, {a:2, b:[1,3,5]}, ...]
```

What I need to do is make nodes with parameter `a`, and connect them to all the nodes in the list `b` that have that value for `a`. So the first node will connect to nodes 2, 5 and 6. Right now I'm using Python's neo4jrestclient to populate but it's taking a long time. Is there a faster way to populate?

Currently this is my script:

```
break_list = []
for each in ans[1:]:
    ref = each[0]
    q = """MATCH n WHERE n.url = '%s' RETURN n;""" %(ref)
    n1 = gdb.query(q, returns=client.Node)[0][0]
    for link in each[6]:
        if len(link)>4:
            text,link = link.split('!__!')
            q2 = """MATCH n WHERE n.url = '%s' RETURN n;""" %(link)
            try:
                n2 = gdb.query(q2, returns=client.Node)
                n1.relationships.create("Links", n2[0][0], anchor_text=text)
            except:
                break_list.append((ref,link))
```

Comment: have you tried py2neo?

Comment: why would that be faster?

Comment: and why are people downvoting this?  It seems like a valid question to me.  Populating 100,000 nodes will takes days using the current technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider converting your JSON to CSV (using some like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)), then you could use the [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) Cypher tool for import. `LOAD CSV` is optimized for data import so you will have much better performance using this method. With your example the `LOAD CSV` script would look something like this:

Your JSON converted to CSV:

```
"a","b"
"1","2,5,6"
"2","1,3,5"
```

First create uniqueness constraint / index. This will ensure only one Node is created for any "name" and create an index for faster lookup performance.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE;
```

Given the above CSV file this Cypher script can be used to efficiently import data:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file.csv" AS row
MERGE (a:Person{name: row.a})
WITH a,row
UNWIND split(row.b,',') AS other
MERGE (b:Person {name:other})
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(b);
```

**Other option**

Another option is to use the JSON as a parameter in a Cypher query and then iterate through each element of the JSON array using `UNWIND`.

```
WITH {d} AS json
UNWIND json AS doc
MERGE (a:Person{name: doc.a})
WITH doc, a
UNWIND doc.b AS other
MERGE (b:Person{name:other})
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(b);
```

Although there might be some performance issues with a very large JSON array. See some examples of this [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/) and [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/23/neo4j-loading-json-documents-with-cypher/).